# Mocking ExecuteMultipleResponse

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamics-crm, fakexrmeasy

is there any way to mock ExecuteMultipleResponse class? At the moment I am trying to write unit test using Fake Xrm Easy, but i am getting the following error:

> **FakeXrmEasy.Abstractions.Exceptions.PullRequestException:** 'Exception: The organization request type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteMultipleRequest' is not yet supported... but we DO love pull requests so please feel free to submit one! :). This functionality is not available yet. Please consider contributing to the following Git project https://github.com/DynamicsValue/fake-xrm-easy by cloning the repository and issuing a pull request and/or raising an issue.'

Comment: This questions seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862663/executemultipleresponse-dynamics-crm-unit-tests-error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.